# How do I properly choose a value for 'phi'

Tags: mathematical-statistics, python, tweedie-distribution

How does one choose the proper value for the `phi` parameter in a random tweedie sample.

I'm trying to properly choose the correct value for the 'phi' parameter for a random sampling of a tweedie distribution.  I'm doing this to see if the result of my tweedie random sampling matches the distribution of the target variable of that I'm developing a GLM for.

This is the code I'm using:

```
import tweedie
mean = 353.78
std = 17298.24
size = 860310

tvs = tweedie.tweedie(mu = mean, p = 1.5, phi = 1).rvs(size)

n = len(tvs)

g = plt.step(np.sort(tvs), np.arange(1, n+1)/float(n), where='post')
```

When I change `phi` the resulting graph drastically changes.  Can anyone help me learn to properly calculate phi?  It doesn't have to be code, just something I can turn into code.

Thank you.

Comment: From what information do you wish to "calculate" phi?  Your example shows no calculation at all!

Comment: correct.  Every example I see has an arbitrary value for the parameter 'phi'.  I want to know how that parameter should be calculated so I can put the correct parameter in there.  Is that clear?

Comment: It's not clear because we haven't advanced the conversation at all: if you have no information, it's impossible to "calculate" anything.  You need to specify what quantitative information you have available (or are willing to assume).

Comment: Ok.  Let me reword the question.